# Split element into a new list in python

Tags: python

Here my list is like this:

```
['Jeoe Pmith H 158.50\n', 'Ppseph Ksdian h 590.00\n', 'll Mos K 89.0\n', 'Wncy Bwn  j -97.0\n', 'May KAss S  33.58\n', 'Ai Hami s 670.0\n', 'Age Karn J 674.50\n', 'Loe AIUms s 87000.0\n', 'karl Marx J 67400.9\n', 'Joeh Stig S 34.8\n']
```

How do it split the element in this list, and make it into 3 new list like this:

```
[' Jeoe Pmith', 'Ppseph Ksdian', ....'Joeh Stig']

['H' , 'h', 'K', .....'S']

['158.50', '590.00'....'34.8'] #(for this list, getting rid of \n as well)
```

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
>>> l = ['Jeoe Pmith H 158.50\n', 'Ppseph Ksdian h 590.00\n', 'll Mos K 89.0\n', 'Wncy Bwn  j -97.0\n', 'May KAss S  33.58\n', 'Ai Hami s 670.0\n', 'Age Karn J 674.50\n', 'Loe AIUms s 87000.0\n', 'karl Marx J 67400.9\n', 'Joeh Stig S 34.8\n']
>>> zip(*(el.rsplit(None, 2) for el in l))
[('Jeoe Pmith', 'Ppseph Ksdian', 'll Mos', 'Wncy Bwn', 'May KAss', 'Ai Hami', 'Age Karn', 'Loe AIUms', 'karl Marx', 'Joeh Stig'), ('H', 'h', 'K', 'j', 'S', 's', 'J', 's', 'J', 'S'), ('158.50', '590.00', '89.0', '-97.0', '33.58', '670.0', '674.50', '87000.0', '67400.9', '34.8')]
```

(It gives a list of tuples rather than a list of lists, but that's easy to change if you care about it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
L = ['Jeoe Pmith H 158.50\n', 'Ppseph Ksdian h 590.00\n', 'll Mos K 89.0\n', 'Wncy Bwn  j -97.0\n', 'May KAss S  33.58\n', 'Ai Hami s 670.0\n', 'Age Karn J 674.50\n', 'Loe AIUms s 87000.0\n', 'karl Marx J 67400.9\n', 'Joeh Stig S 34.8\n']

L = [s.strip().rsplit(None,2) for s in L]
first = [s[0] for s in L]
second = [s[1] for s in L]
third = [s[2] for s in L]
```

Output:

```
In [10]: first
Out[10]: 
['Jeoe Pmith',
 'Ppseph Ksdian',
 'll Mos',
 'Wncy Bwn',
 'May KAss',
 'Ai Hami',
 'Age Karn',
 'Loe AIUms',
 'karl Marx',
 'Joeh Stig']

In [11]: second
Out[11]: ['H', 'h', 'K', 'j', 'S', 's', 'J', 's', 'J', 'S']

In [12]: third
Out[12]: 
['158.50',
 '590.00',
 '89.0',
 '-97.0',
 '33.58',
 '670.0',
 '674.50',
 '87000.0',
 '67400.9',
 '34.8']
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! but can you kinda explain this line of code please? L = [s.strip().rsplit(None,2) for s in L]

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution, just for reference:

```
lines = ['Jeoe Pmith H 158.50\n', 'Ppseph Ksdian h 590.00\n']

list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

for line in lines:
    cleaned = line.strip()  # drop the newline character
    splitted = cleaned.rsplit(' ', 2)  # split on space 2 times from the right
    list1.append(splitted[0])
    list2.append(splitted[1])
    list3.append(splitted[2])

print list1, list2, list3
```

Comment: Why do you say this is the most basic solution? It involves `rsplit` as the others. And don't use list comprehension but instead has a foor loop. Also you have to declare three lists.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda precisely because it does not have list comprehensions or zip and splice. That makes it a basic solution.